# How can i use an angular js filter to format values in an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angular-filters, selectize.js

I've used angular filters to do all kinds of fun formatting, but always on primitive values. For example, filtering numbers into a currency format.

How would I do that same kind of filtering for an array of values? For example

```
price = 1
prices = [1,2,3]
```

Assuming currency is the currency filter mentioned in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency

```
{{price | currency}}
```

would return $1.00

I would like

```
{{prices | currency}}
```

to return [$1.00,$2.00,$3.00]

how can i write a filter that does that? Or is there a different tool i should be using?

For more background...I'm using this array inside of the [angular-selectize plugin](https://github.com/machineboy2045/angular-selectize). I don't have the option of using ng-repeat on my values.

Comment: Well, you could just use ng-repeat to get to the individual values, then the filter will work. Can you give us more information about what you hope to do with the formatted values? IE are you just going to display them? Is there additional processing? ETC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `currency` filter applies to a single value. If you want a filter that applies to an array, you need to add your own, such as:

```
angular.module('yourModule')
.filter('currenyArray', function($filter) {
  return function(input, uppercase) {
    input = input || [];
    var out = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      out.push($filter('currency')(input[i]))
    }
    return out;
  };
})
```

However this will return an array. If you do want to write the array, you need to adapt the function to compute a string instead of an array.