# When Invoke Filter by js in angular its return null

Tags: angularjs

Im new in Angular, And Im try to Using filter by JavaScript in angularJS, But Im get null..

```
app.controller('aneesFilters', function($filter){
    this.filterItem = filterItems;
    this.filterJSItem = $filter('currency')(filterItems, 'price');

});

var filterItems = [
    {price: 1254},
    {price: 154},
    {price: 963},
    {price: 1880},
];
```

html code:

```
    <div ng-controller="aneesFilters as filter">
        <div ng-repeat="item in filter.filterItem">
            <div>{{item.price | currency}}</div>
            <div>{{item.price | currency:"JOD"}}</div>
            <div>{{item.price | currency:"JOD":0}}</div>
            <hr />
        </div>

        <h2>By javascript (Used filter in controller)</h2>
        <div ng-repeat="item in filter.filterJSItem">
            <div>{{item.price}}</div>
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>
```

surly, code work when Im using filter on Expression, problem was happened when call FilterJsItem ..

thanks a lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595124/how-can-i-use-an-angular-js-filter-to-format-values-in-an-array

Comment: My problem was happed since I have object in array, Im try to use like examples, but also it return null ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VujgewoUrcYnQix7TeBN?p=preview)

Basically  I've created another filter which uses currency filter and works on array modifies it and returns filtered array.

// Code goes here

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.filter('currenyArray',  function($filter) {
  return function(input, format, prop) { 
    input = input || [];
    var out = angular.copy(input);

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      var p = $filter('currency')(input[i][prop],format);

      out[i][prop] = p;
       console.log( input[i][prop])
    }
    return out; 
  };
})

app.controller('myCtrl', function($filter, $scope){

  $scope.filterItem = [
    {price: 1254},
    {price: 154},
    {price: 963},
    {price: 1880},
];    



$scope.filterJS2 = $filter('currenyArray')($scope.filterItem, 'USD', 'price');

});
```

Comment: thank you, its work But Im do some changes like change $scope.filterJS2 to this.filterJS2 ..And set ng-repeat in html to repeat item ...(Y)

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('aneesFilters', function($filter){
    this.filterItem = filterItems;
    this.filterJSItem = $filter('currency')(filterItems.price);

});
```

Comment: Change 3rd line of controller to this.filterJSItem = $filter('currency')(filterItems.price);